# How to make a vector of matrices in numpy

Tags: arrays, numpy, matrix, numpy-ndarray

I would like to create a vector of the same matrix in numpy (so as an array). Let's say the matrix is:

```
w = np.array([[1,2],
              [3,4],
              [5,6]])
```

Then, how can I create a vector of a fixed length with the matrix `w` in every position?

That is: `vector[0] = ... = vector[n] = w`

Comment: Would a 3d array do the job, one with shape (n,3,2)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the exact expected output, to to create an additional dimension you could use [`numpy.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
n = 3
vector = np.tile(w, (n, 1, 1))
```

*NB. `vector` is not really a (1D) vector it is a 3D array*

output:

```
# vector
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4],
        [5, 6]],

       [[1, 2],
        [3, 4],
        [5, 6]],

       [[1, 2],
        [3, 4],
        [5, 6]]])

# vector[0]
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```